# how to cursor move time change color in panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need change color in run time in panel

```
        <span class="Apple-style-span" 
            style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-collapse: separate; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 26px; orphans: 2; text-align: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px; -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; ">
        <span class="Apple-style-span" 
            style="background-color: rgb(221, 75, 57); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">
        <div class="head" 
            style="margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 0px; font: normal normal normal 13px/27px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 26px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; text-indent: 15px; background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); ">
            <h6 style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font: normal normal normal 13px/27px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 30px; font-size: large; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; font-weight: bolder; background-color: #999999; color: #000000;">
                Domain Name Registration</h6>
            <div class="price" 


                style="border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 26px; background-color: #999999; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; top: 49px; left: 0px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 259px;">
                <p class="MsoNormal">
                    <b><span 
                        style="font-size:13.5pt;
```

font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">
                        Sliver Plan

Hosting
                
                    10 HTML Pages
                
                    Flash Header
                
                    Domain Forwarding
                
                    SEO Friendly

```
                <li style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; font: normal normal normal 13px/27px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 26px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-style: initial; border-color: initial; background-color: #CCCCCC;">
                Now Special Offer!!!</li>
            </span></span>
        </ul>
        </span></span>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery for that purpose:

$.("#yourobjectid" or ".classname").css({"background-color:#ababab"})

[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) you can read about mouse events